# scope collision while writing a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to write a simple jQuery plugin just to see how its done. But i cant seem to run it twice simultaneously. Its basically a count down and all it does is get the text() value in a div and count it down until it reaches 1.

```
$('#box1').startCounter();
$('#box2').startCounter();
```

This call changes both `this` variables inside the function to point to #box2. Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CzyNG/3/)

Its pretty confusing how `this` changes around in a jQuery plugin. thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined `$this` in global scope, so when `startCount` is called on the second element, the value is overwritten. Use `var` to make it local:

```
var $this = this;
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CzyNG/11/)

---

Instead of invoking the function again the element, you could also do something like this:

```
$.fn.startCount = function(count, div) {
    count = (count) ? count : parseInt($('span.no-display',this).text());
    var $target =  $('div.counter', this);

    var run = function() {
        if (count <= 1) {
            this.fadeOut().mouseout();
        }       
        else {
            count--;
            $target.text(count);
            setTimeout(run, 1000);
        }
    };
    run();
}
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/CzyNG/15/)

---

And to make your plugin work in environments where `$` does not refer to `jQuery` ([`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)), you should do:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.startCount = ...
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: @Shafee besides thanking you can: a) upvote this answer b) mark it as the accepted one. I recommend you do both

Comment: yehh :D Also could you please explain to me why i need to make a copy of `this` into `$this` for it to work? http://jsfiddle.net/CzyNG/16/

Comment: @Shafee: Because `this` is special and the value of it depends on how the function was called. Every function has it's own `this` (in a way). Inside the `setTimeout` callback, `this` will refer to `window`.